# "traffic volume in Kyoto" or "the traffic volume in Kyoto"

Tags: definite-article, zero-article

(1) Traffic volume in the city of Kyoto is displayed in the graph.

(2) **The** traffic volume in the city of Kyoto is displayed in the graph.

**Question:** Which sentence is correct?

I asked two Japanese teachers of English. One says only (1) is correct, and the other says only (2) is correct. I am confused.

Comment: They're both wrong to claim that theirs is the *only* way, but I'm more perplexed by how someone could find fault with #2.

Comment: You might prefer one or the other depending on whether you're showing a particular measurement (e.g. the different types of traffic on a particular day), or a combination of measurements over time.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, both sentences are correct. They mean the same.
This is a common feature of English, the definite article is not always essential and can be a matter of style or preference.
However you need **the** if you are referring to a particular thing or something that has been mentioned already.
**The** study of mathematics … (as opposed to any other subject)
Several vehicles were involved in the accident, **the** car was written off. (We already know about vehicles, the car is a specific one)

Comment: Thank you very much, Peter Jennings. I don't know why (1) is correct. Perhaps, the definite article is omitted in English more often than in other languages.

Comment: @Kaguyahime I think that the optional **the** mostly occurs in sentences with  the simple structure "[**The**] subject does something to the object" for example "**The** fish swim in the water",  "**The** snow falls on the ground**. Then there is also things like "**The** cake tastes good", but in this case **The cake** is a specific one whilst just **cake** is cakes in general.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are grammatically correct, but sentence 2 is more accurate, with the use of "the" implying it is referring to the specific traffic volume in Kyoto that the graph displays.